# What are the use of ID and Kind of a wireless sensor node in Omnet?

Tags: omnet++

How and why sensor node Id is used ?
what are the different type of kind of a sensor node?
why kind is used ?
i need some example of using kind in sensor node application.
Need references and help.

Answer (score 0):

setKind() and getKind() are used to set different type of sensor nodes you want to create through the msg packet they send.you can setKind() for different type of message packets. for example for mobile node you may want to get location of node  through msg packet you received  you can set a kind to that msg packet at sending end let call it "positionMsg". similarly you can use getKind() ar receiving end to identify that whether the message was for positionMsg or something else.you can give  identity to node as well as message using these methods. Similarly you can setKind() for msg packet delivered by different nodes.And at receiving end you can getKind() to identify from which node message was sent.
similarly you can use setId() and getId() method to use identify different sensor nodes. These methods are useful when you are working with multiple types of nodes .
Sensor nodes can be of different types.It all depends on yours implementation. It is implemented using simple module or compound module.Its nature may vary upon implementation.You can use them as router / gateway,cluster head ,  mobile node(data mules) etc depending upon your need.
For more information you can use omnet++ user manual  1>https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/Manual.pdf
  use this link for implementation guide https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/api/classcMessage.html

Comment: Thank You Rahul Kumar Singh. Actually i need a sample code or example in it. Would you please mention me the page or chapter of that manual because i continue reading in it but not yet find.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use tictoc tutorial and and use these methods with cMessage objects.